# How do I make really big text in graphics.py?

Tags: python, graphics

The highest you can go in grahics.py for size is "36". Is there any way I can make it bigger than that? Is there some other object type i can use?

Comment: Your question is much too vague to be answered. What is `graphics.py`? Do you mean the font in your editor or in your output? Is this really a PyCharm-specific question? You should also read [ask] if you haven't already.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky if you don't know what graphics.py is, then you can't answer this question anyway, so why bother commenting?

Comment: It wasn't immediately obvious from your question that you meant the Python package, since `graphics.py` can also easily refer to a Python file called `graphics`. No need to be snippy.